# C++ Array input not accepting certain number of integers

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, vector

I am tasked to create a problem that finds two of the closest numbers from an input of 10, 100, and 1000 random integers. Yes this is for school, data structure and algorithm analysis, but even in my second level c++ course I just had to code "every day" programs and not these "mathematical" questions. I am to the point where I can no longer understand what is going on.

The program works by asking how many elements are you wanting to insert. 
So enter "10".
Then enter 10 random elements. Done it works fine.

Now when I go to enter 1000 elements it does nothing. or if I increase the random number say any number could be 1-500, it does nothing.

What is causing this program to accept some input and not other input?

I would really appreciate any pointers, hints, or anything, I'm having a hard time in this course and it's the first week.

```
#include iostream
#include vector
#include chrono

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

vector <pair<double, double>> ans;
double *arr = new double [1200000];

int main()
{
    int elements;

    cout << "Enter number of array elements: ";
    cin >> elements;

    cout << "Enter the elements: " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++)
        cin >> arr[i];

    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();

    //    Sort the array
    sort(arr, arr + elements);

    int smallest = INT_MAX;

    for (int i = 1; i < elements; i++)
    {
        if ((arr[i] - arr[i - 1]) <= smallest)
        {
            if ((arr[i] - arr[i - 1] ) < smallest)
                ans.clear();

            smallest = arr[i] - arr[i - 1];
            ans.push_back({arr[i - 1], arr[i]});
         }
     }

    auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();

    cout << "\n\n******* The closest Pair(s) *******" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < ans.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "      \t\t" << ans[i].first << "\t " << ans[i].second << endl;
    }

    auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start);

    cout << "Time taken by the function: "
         << duration.count() << " microseconds" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it "does nothing" and not "is busy working with data you provided"?

Comment: Compile your code before posting it. You forgot the <> in the includes.

Comment: Also you might want to allocate the array to be of size 'elements' and also check whether elements is a positive integer.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen, I think your edit may have hidden the issue of missing `<>` on the includes...

Comment: Are you inputting 1000 random numbers by hand?

Comment: @ChrisMM "Fixed" that back, but I think it must have been a typo on SO, or else OP would not be able to input any number in their program...

Comment: Describe a sample of your input.    It is possible that the way you are doing that is a problem.  For example, entering `10, 20, 30` will place `std::cin` in an error state after reading the `10`  (since your code only reads `int` values, it can't cope with non-numeric input), so no further input will be accepted, and your program will appear to do nothing.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen, ah, you may be right. But SO doesn't drop `<>` when copying and pasting, so I'm a bit confused on that now :P

Comment: If you can don't rely on any input, but try to reproduce the error with hard coded data. This is easier to reproduce for us.

Comment: Also it works for me with 10000 random elements. Takes about 19105 microseconds according to your program. Are you really sure that it doesn't just take forever on your pc?

Comment: @Peter I am just typing 10, 100, 1000 just like that.

Comment: @Max Langhof I am not inputting 1000 elements by hand either... lol.

Comment: The #include has <> it just hid the tags while I typed it on SO so I left them off. I am running it on a 2017 macbook pro... So it isn't taking forever, and when I paste the elements and press enter it does nothing.

Comment: If you are typing values separated by commas, that explains your problem.   Input is failing.

Comment: @Peter sorry no commas, just copy and pasted from random.org

Answer (score 0):

1 If you want to compare 'integers' instead of floats(double), then use 'size_t' instead of 'double'

2 It is better to define and use 'arr' like this:
  vector arr;
  ...
  arr.resize(elements);
  ...
  sort(arr.begin(),arr.end());
then 'arr' can be used as a 'double*' and get rid of deleting 'arr' by hands.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I’m not sure where these edits need to go.

Comment: ok. it just some suggestions but not an answer directly to the question. may be i should move them to comments.